# GET Method failed to return resource

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, wamp

I am hosting a webpage in WAMP and keep on receiving this error in the `Chrome Developer Console`

`GET http://localhost/surveys/Internet.json                    survey.js:368`

my survey.js line 368 is in this function`

```
function loadJSON(key,json){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var obj = xhr.responseText;
                localStorage.setItem(key,obj);
            } 
        }
        };
    xhr.open("GET", json, true);
    xhr.send(); // <<-------------------------- line 368    

}
```

I have no clue what is going on. I recently tried to reinstall wamp hoping it was just a conflict with another application but it did not solve anything. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Could not find the actual error message in your text, if you can't find the error message, then include your xhr.send() call in Try/Catch blocks. Post the result back here. Also please try to isolate the problem in the smallest possible amount of code and post that snippet in a Gist/Pastebin/Plunker/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in the `CACHE MANIFEST` file 
It must be noted in the manifest that these files need internet connection to become available which in my case I did not.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Files to store on application cache

NETWORK
#Files that would require internet connection to access
```